# Python 3.x.x (using android app so no idea)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

So, I am making a calculator program in qpython 3.
I get a lot of errors, realize stuff but this error is the weirdest!
Syntax error on a elif?!?!
I have no blank lines too??

```
for um in range(1, hg):
        if home[0] == "+":
            results = int(float(ju[0]) + int(float(ju[1])
        elif home[0] == "-":
            results = int(float(ju[0]) - int(float(ju[1])
        elif home[0] == "*":
            results = int(float(ju[0]) * int(float(ju[1])
        elif home[0] == "/":
            results = int(float(ju[0]) / int(float(ju[1])
        else:
            results = home
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing two closing parens on all the `result = ..`:

```
  if home[0] == "+":
        results = int(float(ju[0]) + int(float(ju[1]))) # added two ))
  elif home[0] == "-":
        results = int(float(ju[0]) - int(float(ju[1])))
  elif home[0] == "*":
        results = int(float(ju[0]) * int(float(ju[1])))
  elif home[0] == "/":
        results = int(float(ju[0]) / int(float(ju[1])))
```

Comment: Thx! Such a quick answer!

Comment: @endriklos977, no worries, you at least won't have any syntax errors once you fix as above,